# Selective copy of variables in a class

Tags: java

I have two objects of a class. 
Member variables include String, Integer, List(s). 
One object-`Obj1`, contains the default set of values for the member variables(doesn't necessarily mean that all the variables would have a default value)

The second map - `Obj2` contains values set for few of the variables and `null` for the rest. Now i want the variables not set here(`null`/`empty`) to take the values in the `Obj1` object. Which comes down to selective copy.

I have used ObjectMapper from Jackson for this:

```
public static <T> T merge(final T obj1, final T obj2) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
        Map map1 = mapper.convertValue(obj1, Map.class);//put the variables in a map
        Map map2 = mapper.convertValue(obj2, Map.class);
        map1.putAll(map2);//put all values of obj2 into the default map- obj1 so that they override them 
        T finalObj = mapper.convertValue(map1, (Class<T>) obj1.getClass());//convert it back from map to the Class type.
        return finalObj;
}
```

The Problem i feel with `JsonSerialize` whatever i set applies to all the variables in the class.

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```

But i want to define this at variable level. For some variables `null` may not be valid so i want the it to be overridden with the default value but for few i would like to have the `null` value. **So rather than defining these limitations at a class level using** `JsonSerialize`-**where the same condition applies to all the member variables, i want to define this at a variable level whether it is okay with** (`null/empty`).

---

**Update 1:**

*The object being used here is constructed out of a yaml file and i need to do a selective merge with the default object. Is there any way to do this?*

---

**Update 2:**

*Another way to look at the problem would be that each variable have a isSet property, I want to do a Obj2.copyAll( Obj1) - which calls all setters of Obj2 member variables which have null value set implicitly.*

---

How can i do this?The details may be a bit fuzzy so i'm willing to expand more if required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is not designed for complicated data transform operations, so you will probably need to handle this either by custom serializer/deserializer, or by using simpler Object for Jackson to fill in/write out, and your internal data handling object.

But is this complicated set of overlays really necessary? One benefit of JSON is simplicity, and it may make more sense to simplify your data representation and handling, instead of trying to add advanced combination logics. KISS principle.

Comment: The object being used here is constructed out of a yaml file and i need to do a selective merge with the default object. I'm not really sure if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes more sense then -- I slightly misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. While Jackson does have simple merging capability (with `mapper.readerForUpdating()`), it is not a deep merge. So your best bet may be to bind to `JsonNode`, then traverse and merge trees explicitly. And then convert tree to result POJO with `mapper.treeToValue(tree, MyType.class)`.

Comment: The question can be better framed. I'll try to change it as and when i find a much concise and better way to put it. Since Jackson here can't be of much for the problem at hand, I was wondering if there are any other libraries which might be helpful?

Also, another way to look at the problem would be that each variable have a `isSet` property. I want to do a `Obj2.copyAll( Obj1)` - which calls all setters of Obj2 member variables which have null value set implicitly.

Comment: Right. I think your best bet really, really is to use an intermediate form (`JsonNode` or `Map`), merge mechanically (traversing trees), and at the end convert to POJO you want. There are a few details in merging that are application-specific (what to do if types happen to differ? If and how are Array-values merged?), and doing generic merging of Maps (since then you need not worry about eventual POJO types -- but, if you want to, can consider path, just optional). Trying to do it all in one pass may result in more complications.